# How do you make it so that a button doesn't interfere with the location of drawn shape?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So basically when I add a button it essentially pushes the black rectangle drawn in this program down, putting it out of its given location. How would you fix this?

````
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Grid {

    public class homeGraphics extends JComponent {
        homeGraphics() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 600));
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.fillRect(200, 275, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    public void homeFrame() {
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setSize(450, 600);
        frame1.setResizable(false);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        playButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 30));

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(playButton);
        panel1.add(new homeGraphics());

        frame1.add(panel1);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Grid frame = new Grid();
        frame.homeFrame();
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

> it essentially pushes the black rectangle drawn in this program down, putting it out of its given location.

What do you mean out of its location? Painting is always done relative to the component. So your painting will always be done at (200, 275) of the component.

If you are attempting to paint at (200, 275) relative to the "frame", then don't. That is NOT how painting works.

Other problems with your code:

1. Don't attempt to set the size of your frame. If the custom panel is (450, 600) how can the frame possibly be the same size? The frame also contains the "title bar" and "borders". Instead of using setSize(), you invoke `frame`.pack()`just before`frame1.setVisible(….)`.
2. Class names start with an upper case character. Learn by example. Have you ever seen a class name in the JDK that doesn't start with an upper case character?
3. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(…)`, not paint().
4. By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout. So what you see it the button on one line and then the "HomeGraphics" class is too big to fit on the same line so it wraps the to the second line.

You should be more explicit when you do frame layout. So your code should be something like:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( playButton );

//JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
//panel1.add(playButton);
//panel1.add(new homeGraphics());
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
panel1.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel1.add(new HomeGraphics(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now the code shows your layout attempt more clearly.